# hide load more button if there are no posts left to display

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, html, buttons, infinite-scroll

I added a load more button with the plugin "easy load more" (https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-load-more/).  The button is working perfectly except that it will still show up even if there are no more posts to display.  I thought I had fixed it it so the button would not appear if there were no more posts, but the button is still appearing. Does anyone see my error?

my current code

```html
<?php
/*
 * Template Name:
 */

get_header();
get_template_part ('inc/carousel');

$the_query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => 14,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1)
] );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <div id="ajax">
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post();

        if ( $i % 7 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?>
        <article <?php post_class( 'col-md-12' ); ?>>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('large-thumbnail'); ?>
            <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
            </article><?php

        } else { // Small posts ?>

            <article <?php post_class( 'col-md-4' ); ?>>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium-thumbnail' ); ?>
                <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
                <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
            </article>
            <?php
        }
        $i++;
    }?>
    </div>
<?php echo get_query_var('paged') .' - ' . $the_query->max_num_pages; ?>
    <?php if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) {
       load_more_button();
    }
}
elseif (!get_query_var('paged') || get_query_var('paged') == '1') {
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
get_footer();
```

and css

```html
.elm-button.ajax-inactive {
display: none;
}
.elm-button.is-loading .elm-button-text {
    display: none;
}

.elm-loading-anim {
    display: none;
}

.elm-button.is-loading .elm-loading-anim {
display: block;
}

.elm-button.is-loading .elm-button-text {
display: none;
}

.elm-loading-icon {
width: 1.5em;
height: 1.5em;
}
.elm-button::before {
    content: "v"; 
    font-size:11px;
    float: right;
    margin: 6px 0 0 14px;
    font-family: 'Days One', sans-serif;
}
.elm-button::active {
display: none;
    visibility: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: print `get_query_var('paged')` and `$the_query->max_num_pages` before your conditional check, and you will see.

Comment: I've updated my code.  I've replaced one of the lines with the code you suggested, is that correct? (sorry I got a little bit of help on my code because I am still learning so I didn't know exactly where to put it)

Comment: please remove whatever you have added. the idea was to insert some code to ouptut those variables before your conditional check to show the 'load more', to allow you to see if you are checking for the right conditions; some line like `<?php echo get_query_var('paged') .' - ' . $the_query->max_num_pages; ?>`

Comment: And then where exactly would I want to place this line in my code?

Comment: exactly before this line: `<?php if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) {`

Comment: I've updated my original question code with the changes I made.  Unfortunately, the button is still appearing, even though there are no more posts to display. (by the way I really appreciate the help!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50292/discussion-between-michael-and-user6738171).